# PHP: how to detect items with and without values in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Consider this example:

```
$arr = array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => 2);

foreach ($arr as $arrKey => $arrValue) {
    echo $arrValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will output:

```
bla
foo
2
```

But how can I detect within the `foreach` loop which items have had a value and which ones have had a key + value defined?

Comment: There's no such thing as an additional value. An array element has a value, or it doesn't. Your first two elements have no associated key, so they are deemed to be values. It's rarely ideal to have an array which is a mix of named and unnamed keys.

Comment: You're talking semantics, you know what I mean by 'additional value'.

Comment: Did you maybe write your question topsy turvy and did you mean to ask "how to check for empty values" instead of keys? The latter are always present, for every single entry. An empty value would be an empty string (`[0 => '']`). To filter out empty values use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear. I suppose it is more about picking up the way it was defined. However, `foreach` cannot 'see' that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array would work better as:

```
$arr = ['bla', 'foo', ['baz' => 2]];
```

Then you could construct your foreach like so:

```
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    if (is_array($a)) {
        foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
            echo $val . PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        echo $a . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, it sort of embeds the intention in the structure.

Comment: Accepted your answer because the other ones all go into the elements automatically getting a numeric key (unless the key is defined). To distinguish between array keys that have been explicitly defined and ones that did not, @HamzaAbdaoui, @Rajapandian and @A J ツ mention the solution of checking whether the key is numeric or not, but that does not work in all scenarios. As I said, your solution embeds the difference between the array elements by defining one as array. This guarantees you can differentiate later on, for instance in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are confused is you don't have a complete understanding of how arrays work.

```
$arr = array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => 2);
```

This evaluates to an array of 3, all of them having values.
That's its output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bla
    [1] => foo
    [baz] => 2
)
```

When you push a value without specifying a key, it's key is the first available numeric index.
That's why in your case, the indexes 0 and 1 get the values 'bla' and 'foo'. 2 is the third value you push to the array, and its value isn't 2 but 'baz', because that's the value you specify.

This line:

```
$arr = array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => 2);
```

and this one:

```
$arr = array(0 => 'bla', 1 => 'foo', 'baz' => 2);
```

are the exact same thing.

If you want an empty key, do this:

```
$arr = array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => '');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bla
    [1] => foo
    [baz] => 
)
```

Comment: I understood this before you even considered answering this question in a demeaning way. And it's really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: It's not a demeaning answer. You asked your question because you had an issue, whether it's because you don't know yet how to do something or because yous misunderstood something isn't relevant. There is no shame in it and the purpose of my answer was to make sure that one would understand how array's keys work whatever their level of understanding is. If you felt that way, then I'm sorry since it wasn't my goal at all. If you already knew that, then I don't understand why you call array values "additional values" and said that indexed values "are empty". More information about it might help.

Comment: My point was just to reference the official docs of PHP (for further information). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the `$arrKey` is not numeric then display it.

Try this :

```
$arr = array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => 2);

foreach ($arr as $arrKey => $arrValue) {
    if(is_numeric($arrKey))
        echo $arrValue . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo $arrKey."  ".$arrValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will output :

```
bla 
foo 
baz 2
```

Comment: This is ok if you know it will always be numeric, but what if it isn't?

Comment: @kasimir, if you don't specify a `key`, then automatically it will have default numeric keys such as 0, 1, 2.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant what if the key with the value is numeric?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no associated key for any element, it will have default numeric keys such as 0, 1, 2... etc.

So, `array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => 2)` is exactly `array(0=>'bla', 1=>'foo', 'baz' => 2)`.

So, if you want to single out elements having associated key, you can try like,

```
 $arr = array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => 2);

foreach ($arr as $arrKey => $arrValue) {
    if(!is_numeric($arrKey))
    {
        //do your code here
    }
    else
    {
        //additional code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if key is not mentioned, php will assign default key for value.

```
eg : $arr = array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => 2); will be 
     $arr = array(0=>'bla', 1=>'foo', 'baz' => 2);
```

if you want to separate, then you can check whether key is numeric or not.

Othercase - check both numeric and index.

```
$arr = array('bla', 'foo', 'baz' => 2,'test');

$cnt = 0;
foreach ($arr as $arrKey => $arrValue) {

    if(is_numeric($arrKey) && $cnt == $arrKey) {
        echo $arrValue . PHP_EOL;       
        $cnt = $cnt + 1;
    } else {
        echo $arrKey . ':' .$arrValue . PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Edited : Array integer value index is already present, then just assign the cnt value so it will autoincrement from there..

```
if(is_numeric($arrKey)) {

    if($cnt == $arrKey) {
      echo $arrValue . PHP_EOL;     
      $cnt = $cnt + 1;
   } else {
     echo $arrKey . ':' .$arrValue . PHP_EOL;
     $cnt = $arrKey;
   }
} else {

  echo $arrKey . ':' .$arrValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```